# Disable link action if DIV is visible (jQuery - toggle)

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I'm using the following to toggle between 3 different div's depending on which link is clicked.

Check out this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3dYdh/1/) fiddle.

Basically, Link1 shows DIV1, Link2 shows DIV2 & Link 3 shows DIV3.

The problem i'm having is this :

If the user clicks the link for the current DIV when it is already visible, it removes the current DIV and shows nothing. I'd like it to do nothing instead.

I know the logic required to make it work (if 'this' div is visible - do nothing) but I have no idea how to code it.

Any help would be most appreciated.

jQuery :

```
    jQuery('.viewSchedule').click(function () {
    var index = $(this).index(),
    newTarget = jQuery('.targetSched').eq(index);
    jQuery('.targetSched').not(newTarget).fadeOut('fast')
    newTarget.delay('fast').fadeToggle('fast')
    return false;
```

CSS :

```
   .targetSched {display: none}
   .targetSched.first {display: block}
```

HTML :

```
<a class="viewSchedule" target="1"><span class="viewBTN">WEEKLY</span></a>
<a class="viewSchedule" target="2"><span class="viewBTN">DAILY</span></a>
<a class="viewSchedule" target="3"><span class="viewBTN">LIST</span></a>


<div id="sh-week" class="targetSched first">WEEKLY CONTENT</div>
<div id="sh-daily" class="targetSched">DAILY CONTENT</div>
<div id="sh-list" class="targetSched">LIST CONTENT</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3dYdh/2/)**

You were fading out the current div as well. Just change `fadeToggle()` to `fadeIn()` as `fadeToggle()` hides your element if it is visible currently.

Check out the following snippet,

```
jQuery('.viewSchedule').click(function () {
    var index = $(this).index(),
    newTarget = jQuery('.targetSched').eq(index);
   jQuery('.targetSched').not(newTarget).fadeOut('fast')

    newTarget.delay('fast').fadeIn('fast')       //change this line
    return false; 
})
```

Comment: Ahhh that simple! Thanks so much ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the below code:

```
newTarget.delay('fast').fadeToggle('fast');
```

with this:

```
newTarget.delay('fast').fadeIn('fast');
```

The issue is `fadeToggle` toggles the display state of the element. So, if the element is already visible, it would hide it on 2nd click and show again on next click and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Check the display property and then do the fadeToggle.

```
 jQuery('.viewSchedule').click(function () {
    var index = $(this).index(),
    newTarget = jQuery('.targetSched').eq(index);
if(newTarget.css("display") != "block"){ jQuery('.targetSched').not(newTarget).fadeOut('fast')
    newTarget.delay('fast').fadeToggle('fast')
                                       }
    return false;
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/3dYdh/3/)

Comment: Turns out that this is overkill for what I need in this particular instance but very useful for other things i'm working on so thanks so much for this Suresh :)